# Django dumpdata serializing an int as string

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've been trying to make a custom class/type, defined in a separate *db.py* file, to be properly serialized as an int when doing a `manage.py dumpdata` command, but this BitFlagField always ends up exported as a string, the value accompanied by double quotes, while other integer fields are properly exported without the quotes in the JSON file. The person that made it left the place almost a year ago, so I can't get any help from him.

[This is the class' code](https://pastebin.com/UBPxVcTh) - note that I've fixed the `__str__` function and also changed the `__repr__` to `return repr(self.value)`

This is how it looks after the dumpdata: `(...), "blocked": "8"}}` ; For comparison, two other integer fields don't come with the value enclosed by quotes: `"pk": 1, "bit":8,`. Because of this, `manage.py loaddata` fails:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/abcd/djangoapp/data.json': '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int': (core.userextra:pk=1) field_value was '8'
```

If I manually remove the quotes from the *"blocked"* field's value, the loaddata command works.

If I delete both `__str__` and `__repr__` functions, the object type is what ends up as the data: `(...), "blocked": "<core.db.BitFlag object at 0x7f9f2eb0bf40>"}}`. If I make either of them return `self.value`, it complains that it was expecting a str type.

What I need is to either save that value as an int in the JSON, which so far I haven't managed to, or deserialize it somewhere, but I can't figure out the *where* part, as, in my mind, that should be a simple `return int(self.value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to a variety of coworkers, one of them found the issue. The `BitFlagField` class needed the following function

```
def value_to_string(self, obj):
    value = self.value_from_object(obj)
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
```

Adding it made the dumpdata work as intended, with the field being exported as an int.

"[It was in the docs all along](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-field-data-for-serialization)" - True and I'm not sure how I missed this.